# Append one value from a dictionary to a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Currently I'm working on program that has a large dictionary containing all cards from a normal deck of cards.

What I want to do is append every card used to a list. I'll use randint() to generate a random integer which will pick the card number.

```
cards = {1.1:"Ace of Spades",
     1.2:"Ace of Clubs", 
     1.3:"Ace of Diamonds", 
     1.4:"Ace of Hearts", 

     2.1:"Two of Spades", 
     2.2:"Two of Clubs", 
     2.3:"Two of Diamonds",
     2.4:"Two of Hearts",

     3.1:"Three of Spades",
     3.2:"Three of Clubs",
     3.3:"Three of Diamonds",
     3.4:"Three of Hearts",

     4.1:"Four of Spades",
     4.2:"Four of Clubs",
     4.3:"Four of Diamonds",
     4.4:"Four of Hearts",
```

and then another to pick the suit. Then I want to append the value of the card chosen to a list. So say for example I pick 3.2, which is the three of clubs. I'd want to append that value to a list all automatically.

So one integer is generated. Say 6, another value is randomly generated, say 3,the card would be 6 of Diamonds, I'd want to append the second value, which would be "Six of Diamonds" to the list.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appending it to a `list`.

**Code:**

```
import random

cards = {1.1:"Ace of Spades",
     1.2:"Ace of Clubs",
     1.3:"Ace of Diamonds",
     1.4:"Ace of Hearts",
      2.1:"Two of Spades",
     2.2:"Two of Clubs",
     2.3:"Two of Diamonds",
     2.4:"Two of Hearts",

     3.1:"Three of Spades",
     3.2:"Three of Clubs",
     3.3:"Three of Diamonds",
     3.4:"Three of Hearts",

     4.1:"Four of Spades",
     4.2:"Four of Clubs",
     4.3:"Four of Diamonds",
     4.4:"Four of Hearts"}

used_cards = []

def add_card():
    used_cards.append(cards[random.randint(1, 5) + random.randint(1, 5) * 0.1])

add_card()
add_card()

print used_cards
```

**Output:**

```
['Three of Diamonds', 'Three of Spades']
```

**PS:**
Considering my not complete `cards` dictionary, this part

```
cards[random.randint(1, 5) + random.randint(1, 5) * 0.1
```

generates the random number to get the random card. You may want to modify the range(1, x) to the number you require.

**Edit:**

As @Peter DeGlopper said, you may want to change the way you are storing the cards in the dictionary. You could use a tuple like `(1, 1)` instead of `1.1`, to avoid floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: Don't use constructed floats as the dict key! Floating point inaccuracies will make this not work. A tuple of integers is a better choice, assuming the OP wants to stick to generating card rank and suit independently and not just number the cards 1-52.

Answer (score 1):

```
# you do not have to write all the names of cards. you can use loop method.
# first create a list of suit and rank names and an empty list for cards.
# then use for loop and append all cards to a list.

suit_names = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
rank_names = ['Ace', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
cards=[]
for rank in rank_names:
    for suit in suit_names:
        cards.append(rank+' of '+suit)

print cards

# import random. random has a built in method which chooses elements from list randomly; you can use it instead of ranint.
import random
removed_cards=[]
# create ans empty list for removed cards and append randomly chosen cards to that list.
removed_cards.append(random.choice(cards))
```